# matching string where intitial part variable and fixed end part

Tags: regex, shell, grep

following is the list of instance name from the output of nova command.

```
nova list    

 +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name                                    | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| 6cdc00a7-cfe3-4bfe-bbb1-7980ac1c04c0 | haproxy-instance-vms22updateconfar                         | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | Orch-Mgmt=10.32.1.40                     |
| d0528617-39cd-4098-b34c-0977f5a18414 | gunicon-instance-vms22updateconfar                    | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | vms2.1-net=192.168.0.248 |
| e89dd43d-8021-47c6-9f55-39d8bce3c11b | nsoshim-instance-vms22updateconfar                         | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | App-Mgmt=10.20.0.126    |
| b7ea9059-834c-4196-8706-54cfaab3d177 | haproxy-instance-vms22update                        | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | App-Mgmt=10.20.0.89     |
| 2d4d22e5-b844-413f-8d36-f8b3eb3dea32 | gunicon-instance-vms22update                       | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | App-Mgmt=10.20.0.46     |
| 41c4fdc0-3058-4e39-8207-2c02a611ee22 | nsoshim-instance-vms22update             | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | App-Mgmt=10.20.0.217                     |                 
                 |



SUBDOMAIN=vms22update

nova list | grep "\-instance-$SUBDOMAIN"

gunicon-instance-vms22updateconfar
haproxy-instance-vms22updateconfar
nsoshim-instance-vms22updateconfar

gunicon-instance-vms22update

haproxy-instance-vms22update
nsoshim-instance-vms22update
```

I want to see instance ends with only vms22update

I tried nova list | grep "-instance-^$SUBDOMAIN$"
it is not listing anything.

Comment: To get all lines ending with `vms22update` you could use this:
`nova list | grep -E "vms22update\$"`

Comment: @mnille its not working

Comment: ok, after your edit this is different output to work on. Try this:
`nova list | awk -F"|" '{print $3}' | sed 's/ *$//' | grep  -E "vms22update\$"`

1. Get output
2. Split by `|`
3. Remove whitespaces
4. grep for lines ending with `vms22update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris_vr: Thanks for the hint posting my comment as an answer:

You could try this:

```
nova list | awk -F"|" '{print $3}' | sed 's/ *$//' | grep -E "vms22update\$"
```

1. Get output by executing `nova list`
2. Split by `|`
3. Remove whitespaces
4. grep for lines ending with `vms22update`